How to sort values in different columns from one table to another using openpyxl
I am trying to write a code to sort names from one table to 3 different columns(male names,female names,undecided(names are not in the db yet)) in another table using Openpyxl.
load_sheet = IMPORTED_TABLE["List1"] 
for row in load_sheet.values:
    for value in row:
        a = value.split(" ") #splitting the name into 'name' and 'surname'
        a = a[0]             #taking only 'name'
        if a in NAME_LIST.men:
            ws.append({1:value})

for row in load_sheet.values:
    for value in row:
        a = value.split(" ")
        a = a[0]
        if a in NAME_LIST.women:
            ws.append({2:value})

for row in load_sheet.values:
    for value in row:
        a = value.split(" ")
        a = a[0]
        if a not in NAME_LIST.men and a not in NAME_LIST.women:
            ws.append({3:value})

and the result is this:

So using ws.append in the second cycles continues from the row that it ended up in the previous cycle.
Is there a function to delete empty cells or another way to sort the imported table?

Openpyxl 'append' will always write the values to the next unused row on the sheet. So [on a new Sheet] 1st append will be to row 1 and the next regardless of anything else will be to row 2 and so on for each write. If you wanted 'Jack', 'Olivia', 'Lakelyn' to be written in the same row using append then it would have to be applied as a List; ws.append(['Jack', 'Olivia', 'Lakelyn']) then the next row as ws.append(['John', 'Emma', 'Indigo']). Using a dictionary here is no advantage.

Therefore you need to arrange your names into that list before writing to Excel. If you have to write each column separately then use cell co-ordinates to write to specific cells. I.e. you could write down a column in a loop, starting at 1 [or 2] and changing the row number each iteration.

@moken Ty for ur comms i actually found the way to do my task using cell coordinates

This comment helped me to do the thing i wanted
